# Get-Command -Module MicrosoftTeams does not include Get-TeamChannelUser cmdlet

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

So, I'm looking to do some powershell automation now that my company is clamoring for Microsoft Teams.  I installed the module version [1.0.5 (currently the latest)](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/1.0.5) and I'm seeing [documentation on how to add users to team channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-teamchanneluser?view=teams-ps).
I get cmdlet not found errors when using those commandlets

```
Get-TeamChannelUser : The term 'get-teamchanneluser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file...
```

Low and behold, get-command -module MicrosoftTeams returns no cmdlets with TeamChannelUser (Get, Remove or Set).

I've tried older versions of the module but I'm still seeing the same symptom.  Is anyone else able to reproduce this?  Any workarounds?

Comment: get-command -module MicrosoftTeams

CommandType     Name                                 Version    Source
-----------     ----                                 -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-Team                             1.0.5      MicrosoftTeams
Cmdlet          Get-TeamChannel                      1.0.5      MicrosoftTeams
Cmdlet          Get-TeamHelp                         1.0.5      MicrosoftTeams
Cmdlet          Get-TeamsApp                         1.0.5      MicrosoftTeams
Cmdlet          Get-TeamUser                         1.0.5      MicrosoftTeams

Comment: please, put the info in your Question ... not in the comments. when wrapped in code formatting it will actually be readable ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this specifically, but have you looked into the new (pre-release) [Microsoft Graph PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/0.2.1) module? It includes a lot of "Teams" functions, but also of course more broad "Graph" capabilities, which is important (recall that Teams relies on SharePoint, Groups, etc.).

Comment: I'll definiately take a look at that, but I ended up finding 1.0.21 from the test gallery: https://www.poshtestgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/1.0.21.  I had to install manually but at least I get the Add-TeamChannelUser cmdlet when I run the Get-Command.

Comment: looks like the graph api doesn't support private channels: The latest publicly available version of the Teams PowerShell module (currently 1.0.3) doesn't support managing private channels.

Comment: ah, interesting. Have you looked into this other module option? As a 3rd option, I have a module on PSGallery called PowerGraph365 (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerGraph365/0.0.3). I haven't spent much time on it because of these other options,  but it does give you a function called "Invoke-MSGraphRequest" that can basically call anything, just needing the correct url, that might help in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually install a test version 1.0.21, but now when I run the Get-Command, I see the ChannelUser cmdlets.
Thanks to Hilton Giesenow, I'm going to try his suggestion as well and will mark it as the answer if it works better and post an update.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to get this working. I ended up installing 1.1.3.

This is what worked for me:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -RequiredVersion 1.1.3-preview -AllowPrerelease -force -AllowClobber
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module microsoftteams
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-command -Module microsoftteams
```